# Read JWT Token in a REST Service using AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, angular2-jwt

Following scenario: my Spring Boot 2.0 REST Service gets requests made by a Angular 6 Client over an API Gateway which talks to Keycloak. So the request is made by an already authenticated user (done by API Gateway). The information about user and its roles is packed in a JWT token which is part of the request (in Authorization header with Bearer token).

How to process the token on the service side?

I build an `TokenPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` (based on `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`) an configured it in my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` as follows:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/**")
            .cors()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health", "/info").anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(tokenPreAuthenticatedFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
```

So far so good, however after reaching (and run) of the end point in a Controller the request gets redirected and the client gets HTTP Status Code 302 as a response instead of the data.

Questions:

1. Is the approach with the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` for this scenario correct? (I have read in the documentation hier http://springcert.sourceforge.net/sec-3/preauth.html and it should be),
2. If yes, then how to avoid the redirect?
3. If not, how to do it other and right way?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set up your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as an MVC-type processor, which is why you're getting the 302, rather than the 200 and data. You don't need cors for this so switch it off, you should use ant matchers for paths rather than mvc matchers. I'm not sure about the session creation policy, but I generally set that to stateless. and I would set the login form to disabled. So the resulting configuration would be something like:

```
http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/health", "/info").anonymous()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(tokenPreAuthenticatedFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().formLogin().disable();
```

I don't have the rest of your code, so I can't test this configuration, but it may put you a long way on the right path, I hope.

Comment: Thanx for the response. For the test purposes I have changed the configuration as you described it above however without success. The response is still 302.

Comment: hrm...its probably not this configuration then. I think its likely that you have something else in your setup that prefrencing the MVC handling. What's your AuthenticationProvider look like, and is it correctly implementing `boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)`? in other words, it is actually intercepting?